# rclone to Gdrive error files

Tags: bash, shell

Good day,
I am using rclone to upload large files to Gdrive and I always end up with some files causing errors for example :

```
9975 files to upload to Gdrive
```

output

```
Errors:                 75
Checks:                  0
Transferred:          9975
```

does that mean that all the files have been uploaded correctly or do i loose those 75 files that caused an error.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this means 75 files did not get transferred to Gdrive and need to be uploaded again.